# Gathering textboxes created in design

Tags: c#, arrays, textbox

I added several textboxes by drag_n_dropping. Now I want to gather them all under a textbox array. I know how to create array of textboxes in code but not how to gather the textboxes created during design. Could anyone help please?

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the textboxes are not placed on the form directly but on a container control like a tab control or a split container. If you want to find all these textboxes, a recursion will help

```
private List<TextBox> _textboxes = new List<TextBox>();

private void GetTextBoxes(Control parent)
{
    foreach (Control c in parent.Controls) {
        var tb = c as TextBox;
        if (tb != null) {
            _textboxes.Add(tb);
        } else {
            GetTextBoxes(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you call `GetTextBoxes` by passing the form as argument

```
GetTextBoxes(this);
```

This is possible, since `Form` itself derives from `Control`.

Comment: Downvoter, please comment! I have tested this code and it works.

Comment: Happens from time to time :( We have to live with that. I can't give more points then 1:)

Comment: +1, I would suggest a minor optimization. Use `as` instead of `is` and textbox cast -> `if((textbox = c as TextBox) != null)`

Answer (score 2):

This assumes your TextBoxes are within same `GroupBox` or `Panel`.

```
var groupOfTextBoxes = groupBox1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>();
MessageBox.Show(groupOfTextBoxes.Count().ToString());

var textBoxesWithinForm = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>();
MessageBox.Show(textBoxesWithinForm.Count().ToString());
```

Requires `using System.Linq;`. Please note that `textBoxesWithinForm` will ignore TextBoxes that are within `groupBox` and vice versa.

Or like `@Jeff` suggests but instead of going thru this.Controls and comparing if Control is `Textbox`:

```
 foreach (TextBox in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
 {
     //add to your array
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
  {
    if (c is TextBox)
    {
       //add to your array
    }
  }
```

Comment: Does not work for nested control hierarchy. Recursion would be an efficient solution.